# Language other than English is error format when deploying spring boot on an external tomcat server in linux server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, utf-8, format, utf-16

I am deploying my spring boot project on an external tomcat server in linux server. I have some string text in my code to send OTP SMS to user by multiple languages, but when i send languages other than english, i get wrong format different than expected.
Example:

- Vietnamese error: "OTP: 518461 Háº¿t háº¡n sau 60 giÃ¢y."
- Vietnamese expect: "OTP: 518461 Hết hạn sau 60 giây."
- Thai error: "OTP: 448762 àº�à»�àº²àº™àº»àº"àº"àº§àº¥àº²: 60 àº§àº´àº™àº²àº—àºµ."
- Thai expect: "OTP: 448762 ກໍານົດດວລາ: 60 ວິນາທີ."

But when i run it by internal tomcat in spring boot, i do not get that error.

I have try many solutions like as add config UTF-8 to the config of external tomcat server. How can i fix that error when deploy it on an external tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your Tomcat is not configured to use UTF-8 encoding, which is causing the issue when sending OTP in non-English languages.

I think there are some steps you can try to fix this issue:

1. Set the character encoding in your Spring Boot application to UTF-8

> ```
>  spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
>  spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
>  spring.http.encoding.force=true
> ```

2. Check character encoding in your external Tomcat server in the server.xml configuration file

> Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8"

3. Add the following line to your catalina.sh or catalina.bat

> export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"

Comment: sorry, because i didn't reply to your answer until today. Thanks for your answer, i tried many solutions include yours, but it still got error. Finally, after a long day, i found the solution, which is: Add this config UTF-8 to my pom.xml 
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>